# Sniff packets with wireshark on localhost

Tags: wireshark

I have a webserver in my windows machine running Apache(XAMPP).
I have created an Android application that connect to my webserver at localhost.
How can I capture the data with wireshark on localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a common enough problem. Unfortunately, there is no universal solution for this under Windows.

You can work around it by binding your server to your local IP address instead of the loopback address (localhost). You will need to connect your android device to the network and have it connect to this address as well. After this, you should be able to intercept your HTTP traffic with Wireshark.

Another option is to enable full HTTP traffic logging on your server. Apache has mod_dumpio that will do that (although I have no idea if it's available under Windows).

Answer (score -1):

Create a filter in Wireshark to listen for the address of your Android:

ip.addr == x.x.x.x

Then apply it

Comment: That will not work with the loopback.